# Embedded email settings in windows application

Tags: c#, email

I want to know is there any way to embedded the email setting in
windows application other then storing in app.confg file.The
settings will be static so user dont have to change it during run
time. As far as i know we can save it on resource file as string
 ,but how can i access the settings in my code?

Code:

```
string st = Properties.Resources.cubemail;
//SmtpSection smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(st) as SmtpSection;
MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailSettings = 
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection(st) as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

mail.From = new MailAddress(mMailSettings.Smtp.From);

smtp.Host = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
smtp.Port = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.DefaultCredentials;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
    mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName, 
    mMailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add xml file in your project and mark that file as embedded resource, you can put all setting there

Comment: but will it be visible when it will be distributed in package??

Comment: hello again i could not access the settings with the following code SmtpSection smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(settings.xml) as SmtpSection;
MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

Comment: you will have to do File IO, you cant use ConfigurationManager. Better create class for setting and than serialize value from file to object. You can use DataContractSerializer or simple xmlserializer

Answer (score 1):

Use XML document to store email-settings where you can open/update XML document in notepad like text editor or read or update using [Linq To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

EDIT:

If you've mark XML document as embedded resource then you can read it via Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream() method.

I presume that the name of xml document is `Test.xml` and is created under root with `WindowApp` namespace.

Test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MySettings>
  <host>something.com</host>
</MySettings>
```

To read a resource,

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowApp.Test.xml"));
string host=doc.Root.Element("host").Value;
```

Comment: but will it be visible when it will be distributed in package??

Comment: hello again i could not access the settings with the following code SmtpSection smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(settings.xml) as SmtpSection; MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

Comment: hi i am trying this for 1 hour but it is giving error saying  XDocument.Load(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowApp.Test.xml"));
have some invalid arguments

Comment: can not convert stream to string

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MySettings>
      <host>something.com</host>
    </MySettings>
    
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Application_Name.Settings.xml");
                    StreamReader resourceStreamReader = new StreamReader(resourceStream);
                    String xml = resourceStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                    
                    string host = doc.Root.Element("host").Value;

Comment: Why convert stream? XDocument.Load() method will load stream and parse it.